# C++ Array of Array Products ：exited, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am a newbie in cpp field.
Below is my cpp code. When I use the online c++ compiler, and
why does it happened to exited, segmentation fault, and what's wrong with my code.
Thanks guys.

Problem description:
Given an array of integers arr, you’re asked to calculate for each index i the product of all integers except the integer at that index (i.e. except arr[i]). Implement a function arrayOfArrayProducts that takes an array of integers and returns an array of the products.
Solve without using division and analyze your solution’s time and space complexities.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<long> arrayOfArrayProducts(const vector<int>& arr) 
{
  vector<long> res = {};
  int n = arr.size();
  // handles edge cases as well
  if(n==0 || n==1){
    return res;
  }
  

  int product;
  // your code goes here
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    product = 1;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
      if(i!=j){
        product = arr[j]*product;
      }
    res[i]=product;
    }  
  }

  return res;
}

int main() {
  // vector initiallize
  //vector<int> arr{8, 10, 2};
  const vector<int> arr;

  int n = arr.size();

  
  vector<long> ans(n,0);
  ans = arrayOfArrayProducts(arr);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout<< ans[i] <<' ';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to give `res` an actual size.  As a result, `res[i]` for any `i` will have undefined behavior due to the vector containing no elements.  Consider `res.push_back(product);` instead of `res[i] = product;` but make sure you do this _outside_ the j-loop, not inside it as you are doing right now -- Note also that the special case where `n == 1` will break the caller, since this also returns an empty vector but the caller assumes it has 1 element.

Comment: if you dont know the size of the vector you can use methods like push_back to insert data into a vector and it will automatically resize as needed.

Comment: Thanks all, appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the line where the failure comes:

```
res[i] = product;
```

and the reason is because you declared res like this:

```
vector<long> res = {};
```

so you are trying to access the `long` element located at 'cell' `i` of an empty vector... that is not allowed in C++ and the result is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

fix it:

the same way as in the main function

```
std::vector<long> arrayOfArrayProducts(const std::vector<int>& arr)
{ 
     int n = arr.size(); 
     std::vector<long> res(n, 0);
     ....
```

Comment: Thanks for description of detailed reason. I have learned a lot!
I had thought "vector<long> res = {};"  is a good initialized writing style from C language in the past. Why does it not allowed in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults typically occur when you try to read past the bounds of an array. This fault in your code means that you're trying to read/ write something from an array which is not allocated. If you take a closer look, `res[i]=product` means that your accessing elements from the vector `res`. But you haven't reallocated **or** inserted data into it. This is the reason for the segmentation fault.

To resolve this, resize the `res` vector to the size of `arr` so that the vector will have the elements in memory to be accessed,

```cpp
vector<long> arrayOfArrayProducts(const vector<int>& arr) 
{
  vector<long> res(srr.size());
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for description of detailed reason. I have learned a lot! I had thought "vector<long> res = {};" is a good initialized writing style from C language in the past. Why does it not allowed in C++?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to access the index `i` of the `vector<int> res` that you never initialized. on this line:

```
res[i] = product;
```

For that you have to understand how Vector works, Vector is dynamic container which can shrink and expand based on its usage, in your case, You Initialized it with default constructor, which did not allocated any memory to hold `int`. So when you try to access that you get undefined behavior.

In case of default construction of vector. You cannot assign to a particular index. but you have can put data in it via this:

```
res.push_back(data);
```

You can fix it by using these constructors:

```
std::vector<int> res(arr.size(), 0); // In second parameter you can pass default values for all the elements in the vector.
std::vector<int> res(arr.size()); //This will simply initialize elements with default constructor
```